# Spawn waves of enemies in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm actually working on a space shooter game. I have a function that randomly spawns an enemy, on a random position :

```
let enemyShip = EnemyShip(enemyImage: enemyImageShip, life: enemyShipLife, nodeName: nodeNameEnemy, gameScene: game)
   enemyShip.definitionPhysicsBody()

    game.addChild(enemyShip)

    let spawn = ToolMaths.random(min: gameZone.minX + enemyShip.size.width, max: gameZone.maxX - enemyShip.size.width)
    enemyShip.position = CGPoint(x: spawn, y: game.size.height )
    let moveEnemyShip = SKAction.moveTo(y: 0, duration: 1.8)

     let removeEnemyShip = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    let enemyShipSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemyShip, removeEnemyShip])
    enemyShip.run(enemyShipSequence)
```

Now I want to create a system of waves, like :

wave 1: One enemy spawns
wave 2: Two enemies spawn
wave 3: Three enemies, etc

How can i do that ? Thanks

Comment: This is not an appropriate question.  Can you re-form the question to focus on how you tried to get the waves of enemies to appear?  Be sure to show the code for what you tried, and include the exact problem of where your code failed.  A screenshot of the failure would also be helpful.  StackOverflow isn't meant to be a code design service, but we can help solve a specific bug you're having with your own design. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Control and Flow are the things you're looking for, I think.

They'll let you predetermine how many enemies are created in a wave, how many waves you have and the difference between enemies in subsequent wave.

Think of it like this:

```
If Wave = 1, Enemies = 1
When Wave Finished, Wave = Wave + 1
If Wave = 2, Enemies = Enemies + Wave
When Wave Finished, Wave = Wave + 1
If Wave = 3, Enemies = Enemies + Wave
```

---

This will give you:

- Wave 1 with 1 Enemy
- Wave 2 with 3 Enemies
- Wave 3 with 6 Enemies

---

Swift has a few ways you can control the flow of a game. Each has some merits of its own, and each you can use... it's pretty much a personal choice. You can read about them here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html